# SQL: Conditionally inserting/selecting from a table while inserting into another

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to insert log events into a table in mySQL (but I am relatively new to database work).  I have two tables, one is a table of usernames and user IDs like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I have a table of log messages which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `messageid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`messageid`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My issue is that when data comes I need to log to "messages" I have three pieces of information:  A timestamp, a message, and a **username** (not user ID) and that username may not be in the "users" table (but I will need to add it).  To solve this I've been doing:

1. Select from USERS to get the ID associated with the username.
2. If the select returned 0 rows, insert the username into the "users" table.
3. Now insert the message into the "messages" table with the id, message, and timestamp.

This requires 2-3 SQL queries for every message (which can be quite a significant amount of data).

What would be the most efficient way of doing #1-3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do the following, because you have a UNIQUE constraint on `name`:

```
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('username')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)
```

That query will fill the id for that username into the LAST_INSERT_ID slot in mysql.  You can then use that id to insert into the messages table.

Here is an example, for if it is possible for you to send multiple queries to mysql:

```
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('username')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);

INSERT INTO messages (userid, timestamp, message)
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'timestamp', 'message';
```

If you are using mysqli in php, for example, you would be able to send this via [mysqli_multi_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

If you can't send multiple queries at once, then depending on how you are accessing the database, SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() may not work for you.  In that case, you should retrieve the last_insert_id manually and create a second insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO messages (userid, timestamp, message) 
VALUES ('id', 'timestamp', 'message');
```

Comment: I was able to send multiple queries, so your SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID worked flawlessly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use insert ignore and a conditional select to achieve this in 2 steps.

INSERT IGNORE INTO users (name) VALUES ("raj");

Conditionally use the last insert id or the existing user id while inserting into messages table.